# In codeigniter 4: what is the difference between calling findAll() and asArray()->findAll()?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model

I have a simple question. In my model, what is the difference between calling:

```
return $this->findAll();
```

And calling:

```
return $this->asArray()->findAll();
```

Won't findAll already return an array?

Comment: https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html?highlight=findall#runtime-return-type-changes

Answer (score 1):

I think this is to allow you to change the return type for a specific query since you can specify a certain type on the model like this:

```
protected $returnType = 'object';
```

asArray() returns data as an associative array with the column names as the keys.

```
return $this->asArray()->findAll();
```

You also have the option to specify that it be returned as object.

```
return $this->asObject()->findAll();
```

https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/models/model.html

Comment: from the docs: *These methods only change the return type for the next find*() method call. After that, it is reset to its default value.*